# how to remove url ending /#prettyphoto in Wordpress gallery page

Tags: jquery, lightbox, prettyphoto

When I open my gallery page, and click on an image, after the lightbox opens and closes, I notice ... /gallery/#prettyphoto then appears in my url.

I looked in the general prettyphoto.js file and found something called deeplinking: true. So I changed this to false, saved file and went back to my site, but this does not seem to have any made any change and the #prettyphoto still shows at the end. It would be nice if first, I could remove pretyphoto words, and better still for it to show the name of each image each time a photo opens in lightbox.
I am novice with .js (and php), so I just need some code direction and which file I need to change for this to work. I wonder what that deeplinking true or false does? thank you

Answer (score 0):

## prettyPhoto

If you're setting the deeplinking option correctly, it should prevent [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation) from altering the URL.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
            deeplinking: false,
            social_tools: false
        });
    });
```

Comment: I was changing it in the prettyphoto.js file but this is a much better way. Ok so I went in to my file named site.js and added that code you put (thank you very much for that). However, it still shows the #prettyphoto url ending as soon as I close the image lightbox. How weird?   I even copied and pasted your code to make sure I got it exact. Though I didnt need the first line as it already has the document ready function at the top.  I must still be doing something wrong.

Comment: Sorted it. Updating prettyphoto to 3.1.5 has solved the issue.